# How can I have a dynamic string appear in my view?

Tags: java, android, string.format

For instance, I want to display the datetime/string of when my device last synced with another device.  I have something like this right now:

```
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        String syncString = String.format(resources.getString(R.string.last_sync), fileLastSync);
```

and I saved my resource string in my values/strings.xml:

```
<string name="last_sync">Last synced  %s</string>
```

In my Activity view I have the following:

```
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/last_sync"
            />
```

But only the string notation appears when I run my device.

What am I doing wrong? It should be showing the string of the datetime instead of the placeholder.

For instance, I hardcoded my string as such:

```
String fileLastSync = "09-18-2014";
```

My output:

*Last synced: %s*

My expected output:

*Last synced: 09-18-2014*

Comment: What is the output? and what is the expected output? and where do you add the date&time to the string?

Comment: My output is Last Sync: %s. Updated post to reflect where I am setting the string.

Comment: Can you try resources.getTextArray().toString() instead and see what happens? Or resources.getText().toString() ?

Comment: It also depends where you set the date. You might need to use a `Handler` to post the update on the main thread.

Comment: where u r setting string?

Comment: I am setting string inside my activity outside my onCreate Method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here,

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/last_sync" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/last_sync"
        />
```

and then in `onCreate()` put the following:

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
String syncString = String.format(resources.getString(R.string.last_sync), fileLastSync);

TextView lastSyncTextView = ( (TextView) findViewById(R.id.last_sync) );

lastSyncTextView.setText(syncString);
```

Comment: This seemed to work except I changed view.findViewById() to findViewById() ...  Why do I have to include the TextView information in my activity?

Comment: Thank you for the catch, I changed the code above to reflect your observation. You need TextView in your activity in order to dynamically set the value of it. I usually put all views that I will be using as private instance variables. and then get them assigned in "onCreate()". This way I can use them in any other methods in the activity class with ease ;)

Answer (score 1):

**do like this :**

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLastSync"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/last_sync"
            />
```

Now in  your `Activity` update `tvLastSync` :

```
   tvLastSync=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLastSync);
   String syncString = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.last_sync), fileLastSync);
    System.out.println(syncString);
    tvLastSync.setText(syncString);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your solution is correct too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use getString (int id, Object... formatArgs). Try passing fileLastSync as a formatArg there with your original code.